# Invoke OnClientClick of button in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I have an button in my aspx web page, which should be 'clicked' in my code behind c# code. The OnClientClick method then call a JS confirm dialog box and so the btn_Click function only get executed when user click 'OK'...

This is my code so far:
**Variante 1**

aspx:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirm" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" />
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // set OnClientClick 
       btnConfirm.OnClientClick = "confirm('Save in DB?');";

       // invoke method
       Type t = typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button);
       object[] p = new object[1];
       p[0] = EventArgs.Empty;
       MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("OnClick", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
       m.Invoke(btnConfirm, p);
}
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //save something in database
    }
```

Got code samples by: http://forums.asp.net/t/1046550.aspx?How+do+you+raise+a+button+click+event+from+outside+the+button+

I want to call the OnClientClick method, but when I replace 'OnClick' with 'OnClientClick' this error appear:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Edit:
**Variante 2:**

I tried to rewrite my program like this:
aspx:

```
<script language="javascript">
function invokeButtonClick() {
        document.getElementById("btnConfirm").click();
    }

    function Validate() {
        return confirm('Save in db?');
    }
</script>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirm" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" OnClientClick="return Validate();" />
```

aspx:cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "InvokeButton", "invokeButtonClick();", true);
}

protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // save something in database
}
```

But then the page postback before my btnConfirm_Click function get called...

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `OnClientClick` has a return value of **true** then the codebehind `OnClick` event will fire.  If `OnClientClick` is returned **false** then it won't.

If `OnClientClick` doesn't return anything the codebehind event will fire regardless.  So you want..

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirm" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" />

<script language="javascript">
    function Validate() {
        return confirm('Save in db?');
    }
</script>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // set OnClientClick 
   btnConfirm.OnClientClick = "return Validate();";
}

protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //save something in database
}
```

UPDATE:

This post just came to my attention, don't know why I didn't include it in my original post but you can use 'OnClientClick' in the aspx tag:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirm" OnClientClick="return Validate();" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" />

<script language="javascript">
    function Validate() {
        return confirm('Save in db?');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem which occurred here is that the page postback before the data is saved in a database.. so some data is missing and an error pops up

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you trying to postback, display a message then postback again?

Comment: So for debugging I put some alerts into the code and this is the result: When the site load, the code behind calls a JS function, which simulate a click. So far so good, the confirm message box of the OnClientClick event pops up. But then after the user clicked on 'ok' or 'cancel' the code behind run through the end of the code. The web page reload and at least the alert in the btnConfirm_Click function pops up.. So why get the btnConfirm_Click not get called instantly after the OnClientClick event finished?

Comment: Or is it possible to prevent the postback of the button, but still call the JS confirm and then if user click ok, call a code behind method?

Comment: That's exactly what the code above does. using `return` in the `OnClientClick`, if the user clicks cancel the Postback does not occur. I think maybe you need to strip out some code as it appears you've got conflicting logic happening.

Comment: I don't need a postback at all.. What I want to do is to: 1)Call a JS function to open confirm message box.. 2) If user click ok: call a C# function to save in DB else if user click cancel don't do anything..

Comment: Yes, you need postback otherwise you'll never get to the C# function

Comment: Ok so theres no chance to call a C# function from JS code? And this is normal behavior, that the postback happen right after OnClientClick event and before OnClick event fire? normal  The problem atm of a postback is that some variables in C# get lost..

Comment: You can but this is quite messy and not your original question. If you're loosing variables between postback you've got 3 options; use `Session` or `ViewState` or place the variables inside `HiddenFields` but again that's all different from your original question.

Comment: yeah true, so thanks for your help. I will try to resolve the new problem by my own ;)

Answer (score 5):

You need to Add both the events on the button click. `OnClientClick` handles the Client side script code and `OnClick` handles the server side event calling.
So add both events and there handlers. The `NullReferenceException` you are getting because of that.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnConfirm" Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" OnClientClick="return Validate();" />
```

and in your `javascript` code can be

```
function Validate(){
     if (valied())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can the OnClientClick method not set in code behind like in my question above?

Comment: No `OnClientClick ` is teh client side event so it will be handle at client side using javascript of any other client side script function. Only server side event will be handled at the server side code like `OnClick`.

Comment: What you are trying to do ? Can you explain why you want to call the client side script from code behind ? It will not work that way ?

Comment: I iterate through an array and in the confirm there should be a text like "confirm('Save " + sString[i] + " in database?')"

Comment: I now tried to add both events like you suggested, but I still get the NullReferenceException..

Answer (score 3):

100% code behind confirmation! Sometiems its so annyoing to Code behind or Server side confirmation in asp.net when you want to Delete or Update something, I got its solution after a long search as below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to BLOCK this customer ?')" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Now whenever you will click this button it 'll ask to confirm, if you 'll select "NO" page will not post and if you select "Yes" then page will post and your button click event will be fire... like below

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    } 

 // Before coming here,,,there will be confirmation   
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      GetCustomerInfo();
    }
```